# Which is LongListSelector on Windows 10 SDK?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10

I am a newbie developer and I am so confuse about this problem. In Windows Phone 8.0, I used a control named LongListSelector, however, in Windows 10 UWP, I can not find it in toolbox, so, is it replaced or renamed, please help me!

Comment: http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/28/Migrating-from-the-LongListSelector-to-the-ListView-in-Windows-Phone-XAML-Apps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this was integrated into ListView control. Please, refere to this article to check more about it:

http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/28/Migrating-from-the-LongListSelector-to-the-ListView-in-Windows-Phone-XAML-Apps.aspx

Hope this helps,

Andrew